# How does bundler know which version of a gem to install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I have been using the `less-rails-bootstrap` gem from https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap in my `rails 3.1` project.

I want to upgrade to the 2.0wip version of bootstrap and I found a fork with the same name under https://github.com/sgruhier/less-rails-bootstrap

Both version say to install you add `gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'` to your gemfile.

Well, how is bundler going to know which one to use?  What if 20 people had gems with the exact same name?

I guess the bigger question is how to I specify which gem to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler will use the one found on http://rubygems.org, which is the one at the first link you posted.

When trying to use an unreleased branch/fork, you should pass the `:git` option in your `Gemfile` to tell Bundler to use that git repository:

```
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', :git => "git://github.com/sgruhier/less-rails-bootstrap.git"
```

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense.  But what if there were two on rubygems?  Using the :git, I can see how easy it is to specify exactly the one I want but if there are more than one on Rubygems then how does that work?

Comment: There can't be two identically-named gems on Rubygems. If the author of the 2.0wip version tried to publish his gem, he would have to rename it (he might named it sgruhier-less-rails-bootstrap or something). What should normally happen is that the author of the fork gets the original author to merge his changes into the "official" gem.

Comment: Ah.  So you're saying I was making the whole deal way too complicated?  LOL.  OK, I understand that.  So it's basically first-come, first-serve.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah. Here's an example (http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=raspell) -- There's an official "raspell" gem, and then I published "dmarkow-raspell" to add Ruby 1.9 support before the official one had it.